# Convert an integer to a string without allocating memory

Tags: java, android, memory-management

I've been experiencing occasional lags in my Android game when the garbage collector runs. I ran DDMS and discovered that all of the memory being allocated by my application is from this line:

```
scoreString = String.valueOf(score);
```

What is the best way to convert an integer to a string without allocating any memory?

Comment: Sounds like the way you're displaying things is the problem here. If the garbage collector, or string allocation are really disrupting your game, you have other serious problems that you're masking.

Comment: Could you explain? The garbage collector is probably the most common performance issue in Android games. Plus, the performance is fine except for brief periods (less than a second) when it slows down. Looking at log output, these lags line up with garbage collection.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Allocate an array of characters to be displayed as the score, and use a lookup table of 0-9 (this conveniently maps to a 0-base array anyway) to append to this array based on each digit of the score.

Edit:
To extract the digits from your score:

```
12345 mod 10 = 5
12345 mod 100 = 45 / 10 = 4.5 (floors to 4)
12345 mod 1000 = 345 / 100 = 3.45 (floors to 3)
12345 mod 10000 = 2345 / 1000 = 2.345 (floors to 2)
12345 mod 100000 = 12345 / 10000 = 1.2345 (floors to 1)
```

Also you'll know what the max length for the score character array should be based on whatever you're using to store score (i.e. int)

I recommend reverse-filling this array and initializing it to all '0' so your score will display like

```
0000000000
0000005127
```

Comment: Is that really the only way? Given the amount of math required for that, I'm not entirely sure if that's faster than just allocating memory. This code is in a loop being called many times per second.

Comment: Sure, I doubt it's less math than whatever is required for collision detection and response or whatever other mechanics your game requires in order to necessitate the score changing that often?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem also, if the GC kicks in during a frame it's really noticeble. I came up with this solution.

If you fill the buffer backwards, you can just repeatedly `% 10` and `/ 10`.

A working implementation that appends a number to a StringBuilder, probably not the best way to do it but it works and causes no allocations. You could also use another character array for the values instead of casting to char and adding 48 ('0' in ascii)

```
    private char[] sbBuffer = new char[20];
private void appendInt(StringBuilder sb, int num) {
    int i,j;
    i = sbBuffer.length - 1;
    if (num == 0) {
        j = sbBuffer.length - 1;
        sbBuffer[j] = (char) 48;
    } else {
        if (num < 0)
            sb.append('-');
        num = Math.abs(num);
        while (num > 0) {
            sbBuffer[i] = (char) (num % 10 + 48);
            i--;
            num /= 10;
        }
        j = i + 1;
    }

    sb.append(sbBuffer, j, sbBuffer.length - j);

    /* clean up */
    for (i = j; i < sbBuffer.length; i++)
        sbBuffer[i] = 0;
}
```